# Able to checkout deleted local git branch, why?

Tags: git, github

I want to delete branch **test** locally. So I follow the following instructions

`git checkout master`
`git branch -d test`

After that I check the branch name
`git branch`

Branch **test** was not available
But when I try to following cmd,

`git checkout test`

I am able to successfully checkout branch **test**. If deleted any branch then why I am able to checkout deleted branch..

Comment: Your observations don't agree with what you claimed you did.  Does `git branch` really still show `test` as being present?

Comment: Do you have a remote tracking branch `origin/test` by any chance? In that case `checkout` will create a new local branch from the remote tracking branch. (But the output of the command should tell you)

Comment: @knittl yes, I have ..

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting branch from local repository only.  To stop checkout you should remove it from remote repo also.  do following after local delete

git push origin --delete yourBranch